# Screen Scraping - Read Captcha

Tags: asp.net, screen-scraping, captcha

I am working on Screen Scraping, I was able to do it, but some of the websites have captcha and I'll need to enter captcha information to proceed further

Is there anyway to read captcha information and submit those values that are in captcha or how can we handle this scenario ?

Comment: For your information, CAPTCHAs are there exactly to prevent this kind of behavior; IANAL, but note that attempts at cracking them might be considered criminal in some jurisdictions (IIRC a CAPTCHA has been recognized as a barrier to entry, so breaking it might be similar to picking a lock), and usually the *content provider's* jurisdiction would apply (i.e. "but my jurisdiction doesn't punish this" may not be sufficient).

Comment: Captchas are there to stop automated tools (such as yours) proceeding through the website - are you suggesting your purpose is legitimate?

Comment: If someone has a CAPTCHA on their site then they are explicitly stating they **don't** want you to try and screen scrape their data. Ask permission and see if they have an API available. If permission is denied then respect the fact and leave alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tools that are able to solve captchas. A very popular one is [pwntcha](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/PWNtcha). Before hitting a page with automated requests and solving captchas you should ask the website owner for permission. He/She might grant you access to the page without showing the captcha.

Answer (score 0):

Get a screenshot of captcha at positions x1,y1 - x2,y2.
Send and show it to operator (maybe, to yourself).
Reply to it with a hotkey F1-F5 (bind them to your software to quickly switch into captcha area).
== ~1000 captchas/hour.